# jquery keypress не видит 1 символ

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, почему выводит -1 символ?

```js
  $( "#name-gift-from" ).keypress(function() {
            $('.gift-from').html($(this).val());
            if ($(this).val() == '') $('.gift-from').html('_ _ _ _');
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="text" id="name-gift-from" value="" id="input-name" class="item-label" />



<span class="gift-from">_ _ _ _</span>
```

Comment: Поменяйте "keypress" на "keydown"

Comment: тоже самое, не выводит 1 символ

Comment: извините ошибся имел введу keyup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поменяйте событие с `keypress` на `keyup`. Так как `keypress` срабатывает до того, как изменит свойство value